# python: applying ** operator on user-defined class

Tags: python, parameter-passing, overloading, keyword-argument

I have created a custom class, and I want to use the `**` operator on a instance for passing it to a function. I have already defined `__getitem__` and `__iter__`, but when I try `f(**my_object)`, I'm getting

```
`TypeError: argument must be a mapping, not 'MyClass'`
```

What are the minimum required methods so that the custom class qualifies as a mapping?

Comment: `**` is *not an operator*. It is part of the call syntax. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Easiest way to make this work is to inherit from `dict`.

Comment: I expect it to unpack my object, just like it does with a  `dict`. But what are the methods the object must implement to achieve that?

Comment: Your class needs to emulate a mapping-like object. As @kindall already said, inheriting from `dict` would probably be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 6):

`**` is not an operator, it is part of the [*call* syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `**expression` appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to a [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping), the contents of which are treated as additional keyword arguments.

So if your class implements the [`Mapping` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping), then you should be good to go. You'll need more than just `__getitem__` and `__iter__` here.

A `Mapping` is a `Collection`, so must define at least `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`; in addition most of `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__` would be expected. If your custom class directly inherits from `collections.abc.Mapping`, you only need to implement the first three.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Mapping
>>> class DemoMapping(Mapping):
...     def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, c=None):
...         self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c
...     def __len__(self): return 3
...     def __getitem__(self, name): return vars(self)[name]
...     def __iter__(self): return iter('abc')
...
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
...     print(a, b, c)
...
>>> foo(**DemoMapping(42, 'spam', 'eggs'))
42 spam eggs
```

If you run this under a debugger, you'll see that Python calls the `.keys()` method, which returns a dictionary view, which then delegates to the custom class `__iter__` method when the view is iterated over. The values are then retrieved with a series of `__getitem__` calls. So for your specific case, what was missing was the `.keys()` method.

In addition, note that Python may enforce that the keys are strings!

```
>>> class Numeric(Mapping):
...     def __getitem__(self, name): return {1: 42, 7: 'spam', 11: 'eggs'}[name]
...     def __len__(self): return 3
...     def __iter__(self): return iter((1, 7, 11))
...
>>> dict(Numeric())
{1: 42, 7: 'spam', 11: 'eggs'}
>>> def foo(**kwargs): print(kwargs)
...
>>> foo(**Numeric())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() keywords must be strings
```

Comment: @user3666197 tag wikis are not meant to share encyclopaedic scholarly knowledge. They are there to share how the tag is used on SO and as a pointer for further info. Put edits like yours towards Wikipedia instead please.

Comment: @user3666197 Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360170/odd-looking-recent-revision-of-tagparallelism-amdahl-tag-wiki, where a community member raised an issue with your edit.

Answer (score 1):

[Emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)

> The first set of methods is used [...] to emulate a mapping...
>
> It is also recommended that mappings provide the methods `keys()`, `values()`, `items()`, `get()`, `clear()`, `setdefault()`, `pop()`, `popitem()`, `copy()`, and `update()` behaving similar to those for Python’s standard dictionary objects.
>
> It is recommended that [...] mappings [...] implement the `__contains__()` method to allow efficient use of the in operator...
>
> It is further recommended that [...] mappings [...] implement the `__iter__()` method to allow efficient iteration through the container

Comment: Many of those are for mutable mappings only; a *call* won't need to mutate the mapping.

Comment: Which methods does "the first set of methods"  refer to??

Comment: The ones in the documentation linked to.